# Can I invoke a $.fn function for my own variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, datatables

I'm using `DataTables` plugin to display some data, which have some nice built-in features like numbers parsing:

```
{
    data: 'price',
    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 2, '$' )
}
```

My question is: can I call that function (and using it) to format some custom `var number` I have?

Such: how can I format `var number = 12.456` storing the result on another variable using that function? Do I need some wrapper? So I can format any number I want using different formats (for each number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, although it's a little unsightly.

The `render.number()` call returns an object with a `display` property containing a function which accepts the value to format as an argument. You can see this in the current source on [line 14888](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L14888).

Therefore you can invoke that function like this:

```js
var number = 12.456;
var output = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, '$').display(number);

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

If you need this, I'd suggest extracting that logic out of Datatables and in to your own namespace. That way you have control should the Datatables source change in a future version and also it's much less verbose to call.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: I've implemented my 2 own functions: `function SetDataTableDisplayNumberFormat() {
    return $.fn.dataTable.render.number('', ',', 2, '', ' €');
}`

`function FormatDataTableNumber(value) {
    return SetDataTableDisplayNumberFormat().display(value);
}`. This way I simply call them as I need ;)